# Is it fine to pass objects as raw Strings instead of using JSON/XML?

Tags: rest

I am working on a mobile app where I need to send objects back and forth to a central server. Each object has around 10 attributes (either strings or ints).

When I want to send an object from the app to the server I make a POST where each attribute becomes a key-value pair.

When I want to get an object from the server to the app I simply reply to a POST request with the object's attributes on a concatenated string (e.g., atribute1;atribute2;atribute3;atribute4;atribute5;etc.) and then I parse that data on the app by splitting the string and re-creating the object.

**Question**: Is it fine to use this method instead of formatting the strings as JSON or XML? I opted for this because of the simplicity, and I also believe I won't lose any performance (in fact I might gain some). But I wanted to cross check to be sure.

Comment: Hell, fixed width delimit it for all I care. :)  It's your application and your specification.

Comment: @asawyer, what if someone else might end up working on this app in the future. Then should I stick to XML/JSON, or again my call and the other person just deal with it?

Comment: I'd go JSON or XML personally if only because one day, you may need semi-colons. Then you'll be custom-escaping and unescaping them or you will rewrite everything to use another delimiter until that is needed as part of your text as well. At which point, you may as well have just used one of those libraries. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interesting site showing the performance difference between splitting strings and parsing json. I feel that if you've already got a system set up for sending data, you should be fine to stick with it.

http://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-string-split/4

As for other dev's JSON is a great and simple simple standard to stick with.